# How to change fonts while keeping the contents of each page？

Tags: formatting, fontsize

How can I change the fonts and possibly margins of a document, while keeping the contents of each page the same?

An example is this site(https://econtheory.org), which provides “view” and “print” for each paper. For the same paper, the two forms provide same contents at each line of each page. How can I automatically do that? Is this possible if Ichange the fonts of the document, say from Utopia to computer modern?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the font size is adjusted, just the margins.  When you look at it in a pdf viewer, though, the font will look bigger because the white margins aren't displayed.

Try the example below and you'll see that the same amount of material is displayed with either one of the geometry package options.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.5in,paperheight=9in,margin=0in]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-31]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I did not know the trick before as I always used package `geometry` like `\usepackage[margin = 3cm]{geometry}`.

Comment: You can adjust each margin separately to get exactly the format of TE.